# This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon

Tags: java, android, gradle

[Getting This Type Error Help needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU4tt.png)

Complete Error Message:

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
-----------------------
```

Comment: please post your gradle. Provided information is not enough

Comment: @AnirudhSharma Gradle Scripts?